# Creating a custom view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, custom-view, custom-routes

I am trying to create a landing page for an event for people to visit to see the events details. I have created the view, added a route to the event resources and made changes to the controller but something has been done incorrectly.

Here is my code:

routes.rb:

```
resources :events do
    resources :guests
    match '/landing_page', to:'events#landing_page', as: :landing_page, :via =>[:get, :post]
    # resources :guestlists
  end
```

event_controller:

```
def landing_page
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
```

When I open the landing page i get the following error:

"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event without an ID):"

Comment: You're not passing event id, looks like (the `params[:id]`)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, can you elaborate? because that is the same method for my show method which works fine.

Comment: Yes, and show's url looks like `/events/1`. See the `1`? That is the event id. Which is missing in this case, I'm willing to bet. Equivalent for your case would be `/landing_page?id=1`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev http://localhost:3000/events/1/landing_page  is my URL

Comment: Right, it's nested. But I think it should be in the `member` block. What does `rake routes` have to say about this (how does it see your route)?

Comment: event_landing_page GET|POST /events/:event_id/landing_page(.:format)                                                 events#landing_page

Comment: Ah, see? Should be `params[:event_id]`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That was it! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this, I wanted to document Sergio's last comment here which I believe leads to the outcome I think most people will be looking for. Nesting this inside of a member block should get you an ideal outcome:

```
resources :events do
  member do
    get :landing_page
  end
end
```

Running `rake routes` should now show `/events/:id/landing_page(.:format)` so you can use the same method you use in your show method that just asks for `params[:id]`.

I was wracking my brain for a while on this as rails resources seem to be dwindling on the interwebs.